# Minimise failure rate of captured jquery click events

Tags: jquery, google-analytics

I am using jquery to fire events when users interact with different elements (primarily click events) and then submit them to Google Analytics. What are ways to minimise potential failure in click event not being captured?

A few obvious issues I'm already aware of and tried to address below:
- add a short delay  to ensure code fires
- Ctrl+Click to open in new tab

Any other ones I've missed? In what cases would the code below fail to capture the user interaction?

```
    // Clicked Social Profile
  $('.socialprofile').click(function(){

    if ($(this).attr('target').toLowerCase() == '_blank' || e.metaKey || e.ctrlKey || e.which == 2 || e.which == 3) {
      var newtab = true;
    }

    if (!newtab) {
      e.preventDefault();
      setTimeout('location.href = "' + this.href  + '"', 150);
    }

  });
```

Comment: Google Analytics' failure to capture event ?

Comment: No, jquery's failure to capture the click event. In which cases would the jquery click function fail?

Comment: any javascript error appearing in Developer Console?

Comment: No, no errors. I'm just trying to make the code as bullet proof as possible, cover all the angles where the jquery might not capture the user event.